# Add Swipe Function in HTML5 Video Player

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, html5-video

I am using this video player http://1.s3.envato.com/files/16280451/bottomPlaylist/universalWhite_preview.html and I want to add swipe function in it so that It support for all touch devices.I am using TochSwipe link http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/.I just do a little experiment and add this jquery

```
 $("#vp2_html5_bottomPlaylist_UB").swipe(swipeLeft);
        function swipeLeft(event)
        {
            jQuery(thumbsHolder_Thumbs[current_img_no]).removeClass('thumbsHolder_ThumbON');

                if (current_img_no==total_images-1)
                    current_img_no=0;
                else
                    current_img_no++;

                changeSrcAndPoster(options.autoPlay);
        }
```

but it didn't work out.So basically I want to implement swipe function which changes video when I swipe on video